# Knowledge of Gear 4th through the world

Tags: one-piece

In the chapter 882 of One Piece ("Beyond the Expectations of a Yonkou")

> We see Luffy at the moment he'll use his Gear 4th, trapped in the Flowing Mochi, and his opponents reacts in this way:
>  [image]

This assumes that he has knowledge of both Luffy's Gear 4th technique and the mecanism to activate it. However, Luffy never mentionned it in his fight against him, so it is the first time he sees both Luffy and his technique.

How so ? Is it something that is known over Devil Fruit users, and everyone who ate them has "gears" like Luffy ?

Comment: Well, he did use it to beat flamingo, with a whole country watching.

Comment: Luffy chose to name this techniques "gears". It's not a solid thing. the next rubber human may name them differently. so far awakening is a sure thing for all the devil fruits.

Comment: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31861/can-any-other-devil-fruit-users-use-gears-besides-luffy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot that Katakuri can see few seconds into the future with his observation haki, so he already "saw" Luffy transform into his new form.

It has nothing to do with other fruit users, so far Luffy is the only one who can use "gears" as a transformation mechanisms and it will most likely remain like that through the series.

Comment: Katakuri literally spoilers the next chapter(s).

Comment: So why is he "interested" ?

Comment: @YassineBadache Probably because Luffy still seems optimistic, and now behaves like he has an ace up his sleeve. He has seen gears 2 and 3, and felt the increase in power that they represent. Also, he might have reasoned that he is about to see the moves that defeated Cracker.